# If element has two specific classes, disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of divs that the user can scroll though by clicking on a next and previous button. At any one time there should be only ten divs loaded. When the user clicks the next button, the first div is hidden and the next div is shown. The goes for the previous button. When the user is viewing the first div, I would like for the previous button to be disabled and when the user is viewing the last div, I would like for the next button to be disabled. So far, I have everything working except for the disabling of the buttons.

Here is a loose structure of my HTML

```
<div>
    <button id="logo-previous"></button>
    <div class="logo-image"></div>
    <div class="logo-image"></div>
    <div class="logo-image"></div>
    <button id="logo-next"></button>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.logo-image:lt(10)').show();
    $('.logo-image').first().attr('id', 'first');
    $('.logo-image').last().attr('id', 'last');
    $('.logo-image:lt(10)').addClass("current");

    $('#logo-next').click(function() {
        $('.current').first().removeClass("current").hide();
        $('.current').last().next().addClass("current").show();
    });

    $('#logo-previous').click(function() {
        $('.current').last().removeClass("current").hide();
        $('.current').first().prev().addClass("current").show();
    });
});
```

It seems like the easiest way to disable the buttons would be to do something like this:

```
if (.logo-image).hasClass(current) && (.logo-image).hasClass(first) 
    (logo-previous).attr(disabled true)
```

For some reason, this method doesn't work for me. Is there a better way to go about disabling the buttons?

Comment: You realize it should be `if ($('.logo-image').hasClass('current') && $('.logo-image').hasClass('first'))
    $('.logo-previous').attr('disabled', true)` right?

Comment: you forgot the `$`, eg if `$('.logo-image').hasClass` ..

Comment: Because your class names are not strings?

Comment: Yes I realize the if statement isn't formatted correctly. That's not the actual code I am using but was only an example of what I was thinking might work.

Comment: don't use .attr to modify properties.

Comment: and a missing `>` in the first button close tag.

Comment: @user715564 - Note that in the second part of your conditional statement you check for the class name. But really, you should be checking if that is the id since you set `id=first`.

Comment: Could you post an example on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: I think if a fiddle was created, most of the comments would of been avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can narrow down the code to

```
$(".logo-previous").attr("disabled", $(".logo-image").is(".first.current"));
```

or you can use the sibling selector:

```
$(".logo-image.first.current ~ .logo-previous").attr("disabled", true);
```

Second, you could use the CSS3 attribute [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) by setting it to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector that looks for an element having the ID and also the class.

```
$("#logo-previous").prop("disabled", $("#first.current").length != 0);

$("#logo-next").prop("disabled", $("#last.current").length != 0);
```